# MySql bulk import without writing a file to disk

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a django site running with a mysql database backend.  I accept fairly large uploads from one of the admin users to bulk import some data.  The data comes in a format that is slightly different than the form it needs to be in the database so I need to do a little parsing.

I'd like to be able to pivot this data into csv and write it into a cStringIO object then simply use mysql's bulk import command to load that file.  I'd prefer to skip writing the file to the disk first, but I can't seem to find a way around it.  I've done basically this exact thing with postgresql in the past, but unfortunately this project is on mysql.

The short:  Can I take an in memory file like object and somehow use mysql bulk import operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "bulk import" you mean LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE then, no, there's no way around first writing the data to some file, damn it all. You (and I) would really like to write the table directly from an array.

But some OSs, like Linux, allow a RAM-resident filesystem that eases some of the hurt. I'm not enough of a sysadmin to know how to set up one of these guys; I had to get my ISP's tech support to do it for me. I found [**an article**](http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/linux_memory_tmp_filesystem_fs.shtml) that *might* have useful info.

HTH

Comment: Unfortunate.  I'm capable of setting up an in memory filesystem, but it's a moving part I don't want to deal with so I likely won't.  The cost of writing to disk likely isn't *that* bad.  I just wish that you could handle it like postgresql's COPY operation

Comment: Yeah, it's not that bad. And I only have to do it once a day. But every time I see that piece of code, I have to grind my teeth and swallow hard. The omission is a big hole in MySQL, imo.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent tutorial called [*Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers*](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) that addresses processing large log files, which is similar, but not identical, to your situation. As long as you can perform the needed transform with access to only the current (and possibly previous) data in the stream, this may work for you.

I have mentioned this gem in a number of answers because I think that it introduces a *different* way of thinking that can be quite valuable. There is a companion piece, [*A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency*](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/), that can seriously twist your head around.